# stop jquery until effect finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code:

```
$(".menu").click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
if ( !$( this ).hasClass("isDown") ) {
    $(".menu-container").css("display", "block");
    $(".menu-container")
        .animate({ "height": "5%" }, 200 )
        .animate({ "height": "2%" }, 200 )
        .animate({ "height": "8%" }, 200 )
        .animate({ "height": "100%" }, 1000 );
} else {
    $(".menu-container")
        .animate({ "height": "50%" }, 600 )
        .animate({ "height": "65%" }, 200 )
        .animate({ "height": "40%" }, 200 )
        .animate({ "height": "0%" }, 400, function() {
            $( this ).css("display", "none");
        });
}
// use this class as indecator if menu open or not
$( this ).toggleClass("isDown");
    return false;
});
```

When the *(menu button)* is clicked several times, the effect likewise occurs repeatedly.

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add animation before adding the following code:

```
if(!$(".menu-container").is(":animated"))
```